# With which sign should the modulus function be opened when a point lies below the line? - HW

Tags: geometry, triangles, coordinate-systems, locus

Question: ABC is an equilateral triangle with A(0, 0) and B(a, 0) (a > 0). L, M, and N are the foot of the perpendiculars drawn from a point P to the sides AB, BC, and CA, respectively. If P lies inside the triangle and satisfies the condition PL² = PM. PN, then find the locus of P.

I solved the question using this method below but got stuck at how the modulus sign is opened with positive, and I don't understand the reason "P lies below both the lines". Please elaborate on the reasoning.

[image]

Comment: "$P$ lies below both the lines", as in $P$ is outside the two straight lines $AC$ and $BC$. And the $y$-coordinate of $P$ (i.e. $k$) is less than the $y$-coordinate from substituting $x=h$ into each straight line equation.

Comment: For example, $AC$ has the equation $y-\sqrt 3 x = 0$. Substituting the $x$-coordinate of $P$ (i.e. $h$) would give $y=\sqrt 3 h$, but $P$ is "below" line $AC$, and so $k < \sqrt 3 h$:

$$\begin{align*}
k-\sqrt3 h &< 0\\
\left\lvert k-\sqrt3 h\right\rvert &= -\left(k-\sqrt3 h\right)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @peterwhy thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> $\because$ $P$ lies below both the lines

As in $P$ is outside the two straight lines $AC$ and $BC$. Furthermore, when substituting the $x$-coordinate of $P$ (i.e. $h$) into each straight line equation to find $y$, the $y$-coordinate of $P$ (i.e. $k$) is less than that resultant $y$.

For example, $AC$ has the equation $y-\sqrt 3 x = 0$. Substituting the $x=h$ would give $y=\sqrt 3 h$, but $P$ is "below" line $AC$, and so $k < \sqrt 3 h$:

$$\begin{align*}
k-\sqrt3 h &< 0\\
\left\lvert k-\sqrt3 h\right\rvert &= -\left(k-\sqrt3 h\right)
\end{align*}$$